# Differentiation of an improper integral using JAX and SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, automatic-differentiation, jax

I provide a simple code example of a failed attempt to use `JAX` to automatically differentiate through an improper integral function making use of `SciPy`'s `quad()` method. The function I consider is

[image: Function]

with gradient given by

[image: Gradient]

The following code is able to evaluate the function, but `JAX` throws `ConcretizationTypeError` error when I try to compute the gradient. **What is the problem here and how can it be fixed?**

```
import jax
from scipy.integrate import quad

## Function
def F(c1, c2):
    val, err = quad(lambda x: c1/(1.0 + x**2), a=c2, b=jax.numpy.inf)
    return val

## Gradient
grad_F = jax.grad(F)

## Parameters
c1 = -1.0
c2 = 0.0

## Evaluates function
F(c1, c2)
# -1.5707963267948966   (which is -pi/2 btw)

## Evaluates gradient
grad_F(c1, c2)
```

Throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConcretizationTypeError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_446012/1229440296.py in <module>
----> 1 grad_F(c1, c2)

    [... skipping hidden 9 frame]

/tmp/ipykernel_446012/2999885932.py in F(c1, c2)
      5 def F(c1, c2):
      6     #val, err = jax.numpy.array(quad(lambda y: b/(1.0+y**2), a=a, b=jax.numpy.inf), float)
----> 7     val, err = quad(lambda x: c1/(1.0 + x**2), a=c2, b=jax.numpy.inf)
      8     return val
      9 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    349 
    350     if weight is None:
--> 351         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
    352                        points)
    353     else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    463             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    464         else:
--> 465             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    466     else:
    467         if infbounds != 0:

    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/core.py in error(self, arg)
    998                       f"or `jnp.array(x, {fun.__name__})` instead.")
    999   def error(self, arg):
-> 1000     raise ConcretizationTypeError(arg, fname_context)
   1001   return error
   1002 

ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: Traced<ConcreteArray(-0.5, dtype=float32)>with<JVPTrace(level=2/0)> with
  primal = DeviceArray(-0.5, dtype=float32, weak_type=True)
  tangent = Traced<ShapedArray(float32[], weak_type=True)>with<JaxprTrace(level=1/0)> with
    pval = (ShapedArray(float32[], weak_type=True), *)
    recipe = JaxprEqnRecipe(eqn_id=<object object at 0x7fbf4f643b90>, invars=(Traced<ConcreteArray(2.0, dtype=float32):JaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[], weak_type=True):JaxprTrace(level=1/0)>), outvars=[<weakref at 0x7fbf4c402c20; to 'JaxprTracer' at 0x7fbf4eca5090>], primitive=xla_call, params={'device': None, 'backend': None, 'name': 'jvp(true_divide)', 'donated_invars': (False, False), 'inline': True, 'call_jaxpr': { lambda ; a:f32[] b:f32[]. let c:f32[] = div b a in (c,) }}, source_info=<jaxlib.xla_extension.Traceback object at 0x7fbf4eca1bb0>)
The problem arose with the `float` function. If trying to convert the data type of a value, try using `x.astype(float)` or `jnp.array(x, float)` instead.

See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that JAX's `grad` transform can only operate on functions made up entirely of JAX operations, and `scipy.integrate.quad` is not a JAX operation. If you'd like to do this kind of computation, you'll have to find a JAX implementation of `quad`.

Comment: I was kind of expecting this, but what is the simplest way around the problem to make this work? Can you offer a solution? This is my second part of the question. Is there an effective alternative to integrate on jax?

Answer (score 0):

A simple, albeit less accurate solution, would be to calculate your integral using the trapezoidal integral. You could also use some sort of quadrature rule which is essentially what scipy.integrate.quad does.

After setting JAX_ENABLE_X64=True on your local system and running the following script

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import grad

from scipy.special import roots_laguerre

def F(c1, c2, tmax, N):
    """
    Inputs:
    c1, c2  are the coefficients in the integral
    tmax is the upper limit of the integral
    N is the number of points. Can be low with a higher-order integration scheme
    Output: scalar integral value
    """
    t0 = jnp.linspace(c2, tmax, N)
    return jnp.trapz(c1/(1+t0**2), t0)

c1 = -1.0
c2 = 0.

gradF = grad(F, (0,1))
dFc1, dFc2   = gradF(c1, c2, 15000, 30000) 

print("error in grad1 = %.8f"%(dFc1.item() - (jnp.pi/2-jnp.arctan(c2))))
print("error in grad2 = %.8f"%(dFc2.item() + (c1/(1+c2**2))))



def GLF(c1, c2, xi, wi):
    """
    Calculating the integral using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature
    """
    return jnp.sum(wi*jnp.exp(xi)*c1/(1+(xi+c2)**2))


points, weights  = roots_laguerre(100)  

gradF_GL         = grad(GLF, (0,1))
dF_GLc1, dF_GLc2 = gradF_GL(c1, c2, points, weights) 

print("GL error in grad1 = %.8f"%(dF_GLc1.item() - (jnp.pi/2-jnp.arctan(c2))))
print("GL error in grad2 = %.8f"%(dF_GLc2.item() + (c1/(1+c2**2))))
```

you should be able to get

```
error in grad1 = -0.00005571
error in grad2 = -0.04435208
GL error in grad1 = -0.00258033
GL error in grad2 = -0.00000665
```

You can use the trapezoidal rule for the first gradient and the quadrature rule for the second one.

Comment: Making a static call to The `scipy.special.roots_laguerre` appears to be the best approach for quadrature in JAX. Note the call will need to be captured in order to make it JIT compatible. Then you'd need to compare run times for a given tolerance to see which method is superior.
Another option is to perform a nonlinear map by hand (integration by substitution) which results in [-1,1] integration bounds.